# How to use DOM inspector on RAW HTML file?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, dom, web-scraping

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to periodically scrape some information from different websites, using Chrome's DOM inspector to analyze how to fetch the information I want.

One website in particular (namely TPB) didn't have proper HTML code in it. And so, Chrome's rendering engine had added some extra HTML tags to complete the tags. I was unaware of this and got confused when my code didn't work and didn't output the information I tried to scrape.

Here's the **RAW HTML** code for a table's body:

[image: RAW HTML code]

Now, the same code, but from **Chrome's DOM inspector**:

[image: HTML code generated by Chrome]

**My question is**, is it possible to use Chrome, or another browser/extension/tool to inspect the DOM of the RAW HTML code, as opposed to the browser-rendered code?

This would make the web scraping a lot easier on my end, using Chrome's great inspector instead of reading badly formatted and erroneous HTML code. If there's a better way to this, then please let me know.

Thanks a lot for the help :)!

Comment: you can use phantomjs or chrome-headless if you want to access the *real* DOM. these tools will help you when you encounter a site that generates its HTML w/ JS anyway.

Comment: your scraper will return the raw html, read that.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already kind of tried those tools before. I don't like the CMD-type of GUI though, because I'm more of a visuals guy and want something similar to the browser DOM inspectors. My "scraper" is just a simple PHP HTML parser which makes it easier to find elements, and is basically impossible to debug.

Comment: The answer to your quesiton is simply "No". There's only one DOM, the one that the browser created when it parsed the HTML. It fixes up HTML errors, adds optional tags, etc. during this process, but never saves the intermediary without them.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for the answer! Do you know of any other tools (NOT browsers) that will do the job I'm asking for -- just visually show the raw HTML code and how to get to a specific tag? Maybe I can copy-paste the raw code myself into an HTML beautifier, and use a good text editor to see the relations between the tags better?

Comment: You can use `View Source` in the browser to see the original HTML. There are browser extensions that will color-code it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, the answer is **NO**, there sadly does not exist such a tool, yet.

However, I found another useful, albeit a bit tedious, way of achieving the same thing.

1. Press **CTRL + U** on the desired page to view its source code
   [image]
2. Copy the Source Code
3. Go to https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/
4. Paste the Source Code on the left there, and press **Beautify**. The pretty printed source code will show up on the right with *code folding*, which saves a lot of time!

[image]

code folding:

[image: Code folding FTW]

This isn't too shabby and will work for the time being :)